# Two buttons but wrong event is triggered when pushing them

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-button

I have a very strange behaviour of two buttons:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/main_button_logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_button_measure"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
    android:text="@string/button_logout" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/main_button_measure"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/main_button_logout"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/main_button_logout"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="194dp"
    android:text="@string/button_measure" />
```

I initialize them in my main activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
    this.sessionManager.login();

    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.buttonMeasure = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.main_button_measure);
    this.buttonMeasure.setOnClickListener(this);
    this.buttonLogout = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.main_button_logout);
    this.buttonLogout.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

My click listener:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.main_button_measure : this.readNFC(view); break;
        case R.id.main_button_logout : this.sessionManager.logout(); break;
    }
}
```

Now to the problem: Everytime i push my measure button the logout is called and everytime
i call my logout button the readNFC is called. Whats wrong there?

Comment: You're code is perfect, Just clean and build once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you change a layout for example that only part of the application is rebuilt (the rest, e.g. the sources will use the previous build artifacts if they haven't changed) and a resource ID with the same name in the xml layout and the java sources will actually translate to different int IDs.

Try to put a breakpoint in your `onCreate()` and check the details of the 2 `Button`s you set the on click listener of, most likely `this.buttonMeasure` will reference the logout button 
(i.e. will have a top margin of 76dp for example), and vice-versa.

So just clean and rebuild, it should solve your problem.
You can blame it on the build tools ;)